# Ubuntu Installation freezes on language selection on MacOS

Tags: system-installation, software-installation

I am trying to install ubuntu on my MacBook Pro. I have got ubuntu version 16.04.2 on USB.When installing it shows error for a brief second something like "failed to handle for ACPI object".It asks to select language then there is no mouse cursor, and everything freezes. pressing buttons did not help as well. I tried to search answers on forum but could not find a solution. Maybe I`m new to this and not getting it. Please help!! Been trying to install for a whole day.

Answer (score 0):

you lost keyboard because Ubuntu couldn't install hardware to manage software like keyboard.  or it may not active in this moment or some error. now reinstall may be the only solution. try to use to write with the main keyboard. may be it work.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I read lots of post regarding linux not working and supporting MacBook Pro 2016 edition. Seems like there is no fix available till now. Will just wait till then.